# Labels and references to equations in Mathjax created from Latex with Pandoc

Tags: html, latex, pandoc, mathjax

I am a newbie to Mathjax, so sorry if my question is obvious. Browsing the internet didn't help me.

I try to generate a html page from a latex file test.tex with a reference to a labeled equation.

My latex file

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
An equation
\begin{equation}
\label{test}
x=3.
\end{equation}
Here a reference to equation (\ref{test}).
\end{document}
```

The html code produced by the command : pandoc test.tex -s --mathjax -o test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="" xml:lang="">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="generator" content="pandoc" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes" />
  <title>test</title>
  <style>
    code{white-space: pre-wrap;}
    span.smallcaps{font-variant: small-caps;}
    span.underline{text-decoration: underline;}
    div.column{display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 50%;}
    div.hanging-indent{margin-left: 1.5em; text-indent: -1.5em;}
    ul.task-list{list-style: none;}
  </style>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-mml-chtml.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv-printshiv.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<p>An equation <span class="math display">\[\label{test}
x=3.\]</span> Here a reference to equation (<a href="#test" data-reference-type="ref" data-reference="test">[test]</a>).</p>
</body>
</html>
```

The result in my Chrome browser, equation has no label, and the reference is not what I want :
[image]

Thanks for your help !